# Accessing HTML div id from PHP class

Tags: php, html, fusioncharts

I am trying to learn PHP/Ajax and I am getting stuck. I am trying to get the result of my AJAX request to render in a div element declared outside of my PHP class.

I have a PHP file with one class called `dashboard`, which handles querying the database once it has received the post variable from the ajax query, which looks as follows

```
public function loadTeamMembersChart($teamID, $lecturer_id, $teamColour){


 $db = $this -> db;

 if (!empty ($teamID) && !empty ($lecturer_id)){

     $result = $db -> loadTeamMembersChart($teamID, $lecturer_id);

     if ($result) {


        $response["teamMember"] = $result;

        $teamMembers = $_SESSION["teamMember"] = $result;

        //Pass the results to the below function
        loadTeamMembers($teamMembers, $teamColour);


     } else {

        $response["result"] = "failure";
        $response["message"] = "Unable to Find Team Member Data";
        return json_encode($response);
     }

        } else {

  return $this -> getMsgParamNotEmpty();

        }

     }
```

Then in the same php file, I have a global function that the results are passed to called loadTeamMembers, as shown below.

```
function loadTeamMembers($teamMembers, $teamColour){    

//start to break up the teamMember object and store in variables

$teamMemberName = $_SESSION['teamMember']['all_team_member_names']; 
$teamMemberPoints = $_SESSION['teamMember']['all_team_member_points'];
$teamMemberStudentNumber = $_SESSION['teamMember']['all_team_member_studentNumbers'];
$teamMemberLastActive = $_SESSION['teamMember']['all_date_last_present'];
$teamMemberTeamID = $_SESSION['teamMember']['all_team_ids'];


// The `$teamMemberData` array holds the chart attributes and data for the team object
        $teamMemberData = array(
            "chart" => array(
              "caption" => "Student Team-Member Progress Chart",
              "xAxisname"=> "Team-Member Name",
              "yAxisName"=> "Points",
              //Configure no.of visible plots
              "numVisiblePlot"=> "5",
              "theme"=> "zune",
              "exportenabled"=> "1",
              "exportMode"=> "server"
            ),

            "categories" => array(
              "category" => array()),

        "dataset" => array(
              "data" => array())
        );



        $teamMemberCount = 0;

         // Push the data into the array
        if (is_array($teamMemberName) || is_object($teamMemberName))
        { 

        foreach($teamMemberName as $key => $value){ 

        array_push($teamMemberData["categories"]["category"], array(
            "label" => $teamMemberName[$teamMemberCount]." ".$teamMemberStudentNumber[$teamMemberCount]." Profile was last active on ".$teamMemberLastActive[$teamMemberCount]));

        array_push($teamMemberData["dataset"]["data"], array(
            "value" => $teamMemberPoints[$teamMemberCount],
            "color"=> $teamColour));


        $teamMemberCount++;
            }
        }


        //encode the built team-member array so that it is returned to the ajax success request
        echo $jsonEncodedTeamMemberData = json_encode($teamMemberData);
```

}

Then in the same file but outside both PHP class I have the following script inside my HTML:

```
    <script>

        function getTeamMembers(teamID,lecturer_id, teamColourCode){

        //Variables needed to query the external DB to return required data to populate the charts
         var teamInfo = {

                "teamID" : teamID,
                "lecturer_id" : lecturer_id,
                "teamColourCode" : teamColourCode
            };
        /*
        The below is used for the 'was a student present for the most recent quiz' pie chart. A boolean is set so that the post request knows
        that we only need to call the loadIfTeamMemberWasPresent(); function, as the data was already obtained in the first ajax request. However, we don't want
        to use that data on the first ajax call.
        */
         var teamDetails = {

                "teamClicked" : true
            };


        //Below is the first ajax call
            $.ajax({
            data: teamInfo,  
            url: 'dashboard.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success : function(data) {
            console.log(data) 

            chartData = data;
            apiChart = new FusionCharts({
            type: 'scrollColumn2d',
            renderAt: 'team-member-chart-container',
            width: '550',
            height: '350',
            dataFormat: 'json',
            dataSource: data
            });
            apiChart.render();
        },

        //Once the first ajax call has completed, we can then call the second ajax request to populate the pie-chart graph  
            complete:function(){
            $.ajax({
            data: teamDetails,  
            url: 'dashboard.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success : function(data) {
            console.log(data) 

            chartData = data;
            apiChart = new FusionCharts({
            type: 'pie2D',
            renderAt: 'teamMember-present-container',
            width: '550',
            height: '350',
            dataFormat: 'json',
            dataSource: data
            });
            apiChart.render();
               },
            });
        }
    }); 

        }

</script>
```

However, where I have written `$columnChartTeamMember =...` I am unable to access and render my chart in the div id called `team-member-chart-container`.

If possible, I am trying to not have the HTML in the class itself as other charts from other classes also need to render in other div id's such as `individual-student-container`.

I have tried to read the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual found [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm), but as a beginner, it is leaving me a little confused. I am also not sure if that is what I am after.

I have based my approach on the official docs given by fusioncharts, which can be found [here](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/using-with-server-side-languages/php/introduction).

If anyone can offer some guidance on how I could render my chart in the div-id mentioned, I would really appreciate it.

**EDIT**

In the end, I managed to solve my issue by echoing the retrieved data from my PHP script back to the AJAX request and then building my charts from the `success` call of the ajax request. I have updated my code to show how this was achieved. I left out the handling of the second ajax request as the data was already retrieved on the first call. However, I didnt want to retreive it just yet so I made a second request once the first one was complete. Everything is now working perfectly.

Comment: You can't inject information into a `<div>` straight from **PHP**, you need to inject it via the JS.

Comment: I believe that is handled in the `FusionCharts` constructor?

Comment: Anuga is right, you would want to inject any data into the div from the success section in your ajax call.

Comment: Ah, ok, I will take a look, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the line of this should work for you.

**PHP file:** *class.teamMember.php*

```
<?php

require_once "fusioncharts.php";

class TeamMember {

  public __construct($data) {
    self::loadTeamMembers($data)
  }

  public function loadTeamMembers($data) {

    $columnChartTeamMember = new \FusionCharts("scrollColumn2d", "teamMemberChart", 500, 300, "team-member-chart-container", "json", json_encode($data));
    $columnChartTeamMember->render();

  }

}

new TeamMember($data);
```

Still need to provide it `$data` from somewhere. Looks like your doing that via the `jQuery.post`, but since your not running the `function`: `getTeamMembers`, `teamInfo` is always empty, so I'm leaving that part out.

**HTML file:** *chart.html*

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='unique-id'>Charts will load here.</div>
    <script>
      jQuery
        .get('dashboard.php')
        .then(function (data) {
          jQuery('#unique-id').html(data);
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Say if the following is the `$data` (copy/past from FusionCharts):

```
$data = "{
  "chart":{  
    "caption":"Harry\'s SuperMart",
    "subCaption":"Top 5 stores in last month by revenue",
    "numberPrefix":"$",
    "theme":"ocean"
  },
  "data":[  
    {  
      "label":"Bakersfield Central",
      "value":"880000"
    },
    {  
      "label":"Garden Groove harbour",
      "value":"730000"
    },
    {  
      "label":"Los Angeles Topanga",
      "value":"590000"
    },
    {  
      "label":"Compton-Rancho Dom",
      "value":"520000"
    },
    {  
      "label":"Daly City Serramonte",
      "value":"330000"
    }
  ]
}";
```

You would not need to `json_encode` it in the class. (Could be removed in otherwords)
But now:

```
$data = json_decode($data, true);
new TeamMember($data);
```

And it should be shown in the `#unique-id` `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated my question to include my actual code as well as my interpretation of how to implement your answer. However, I am still getting issues with the rendering of my chart. Have I interpreted your answer wrong? Thanks.